# Changing value while converting Geostattistical layer to raster using Geostatistical analyst

Tags: export, kriging, geostatistical-analyst

I using geostatistical  analyst for interpolation. when geostatistical layer create and I want to export it to the raster the range of  min-max values changes. how could I export GA layer to raster with no changing in values. this image is result  Geostatistical analyst

[image]

and this image Is after exporting Geostatistical layer to raster

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? do you want to apply the legend from your GA layer to your Kriging layer?

Comment: No I mean When I exported GA layer to raster the min and max values are  changing.I want to have the values of the GA layer  when I turn the GA layer into a raster.@B-CB.

Comment: when you are converting to a raster layer are you keeping the same resolution as the size of your Kriging layer? if not some data might get averaged out by some Inverse Distance Weighting method.

Comment: @B-CB. I just enter the same cell size.Is this what you mean?